# "Absent" vs "in absence"

Tags: word-request

We can use the word *exist* in two ways.
For example,

> It existed for 2.6 billion years.
>
> It was in existence for 2.6 billion years.

Can we use other verbs like this? For example,

> The earrings were absent.
>
> The earrings were in absence.

Comment: **in absence** is really awkward. Even if it were possible I never would have said it.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically it is OK, but "in absence" would be an odd usage in your example. *in absence* implies some volition, which doesn't apply to objects.

Normally people are *in absence*, though the more common term is [*in absentia"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-absentia), especially in legal contexts.

> *phrase*
>   If something is done to you *in absentia*, it is done to you when you are not present.
>   *He was tried in absentia and sentenced to seven years in prison.
>
>   He was condemned in absentia.*